# Create buttons with dynamic background images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating buttons dynamically with JavaScript; I want each of the buttons to have their own background image. How can I achieve this?

The code I have so far is:

```
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        function buttonsCreate() {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
                var button = document.createElement("button");
                var Area = document.getElementById("Area");
                Area.appendChild(button);
                button.setAttribute("onClick", "eventHandlerForButtons('" + i + "');");
            }
        }

        function eventHandlerForButtons(alertText) {
            alert(alertText);
        }
    </script>
    <button onClick="buttonsCreate();">Create Buttons</button>
    <div id="Area"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `the images are in an array` - there's no array of images in your code - in fact, there's no array at a;; - makes it hard to help if you say things about your code that are not accurate

Comment: Made the question easier to read. It originally mentions that there is an array of images somewhere, however it doesn't actually show that, so that needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Try `button.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + array[i] + ")";` inside your for loop. Replace `array` for your own array variable.

Also don't start variable names and element ID's with a capital letter, e.g. `Area` -> `area`.

You can move `var Area = document.getElementById("Area");` outside the for loop. This doesn't need to be called 10 times.

Comment: button.style.backgroundImage

Comment: funktioniert nicht.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var listofImgUrl = ["https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png",
"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"];

function buttonsCreate() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = i;
    button.style.background = "url(" + listofImgUrl[i] + ")";
    var Area = document.getElementById("Area");
    Area.appendChild(button);
    button.setAttribute("onClick", "eventHandlerForButtons('" + i + "');");
  }
}

function eventHandlerForButtons(alertText) {
  alert(alertText);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>
  <button onClick="buttonsCreate();">Create Buttons</button>
  <div id="Area"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I my humble opinion, .map() should be the first method you consider when you would like to iterate through an array. This is a perfect use-case:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

// array of however many urls you wouls like rendered. 
//This will determin the number of buttons created
const imgArr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6', 'url7', 'url8', 'url9', 'url10']

function buttonsCreate() {

    //iterates over each array element and use the element and index
    imgArr.map( (el, i) => {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        const area = document.getElementById("area");
        button.setAttribute("id", ["btn" + i]);
        button.setAttribute("onClick", "eventHandlerForButtons('"+i+"');");
        button.style.background = el;
        area.appendChild(button);
    });   
}

function eventHandlerForButtons(alertText) {
    alert(alertText);

    //just to allow you to look at area innerHTML by clicking a created button
    console.log(document.getElementById('area').innerHTML);
}
</script>
<button onClick="buttonsCreate();">Create Buttons</button>
<div id="area"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of button.style.backgroundImage doesn't work. The following code will generate buttons of the image array.

```js
function loadPics()
{
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        imgArray[i] = new Image();
        imgArray[i].src = 'ImageVerkehr/verk' + (i) + '.jpg';
    }
}

function buttonsCreate() 
{
    loadPics();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        var area = document.getElementById("area");
            button.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgArray[i] + ")";
        area.appendChild(button);
        button.setAttribute("onClick", "eventHandlerForButtons('"+i+"');");
    }
}

function eventHandlerForButtons(alertText) 
{
    alert(alertText);
}
```